# Rename file with multiple file extensions

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

There is a vulnerability in apache where a file sampleText.php.txt may be uploaded to a directory which bypasses file extension validation and apache may interpret the text as a php file

Apache file upload vulnerability

Requires regex replace

Given a file name with multiple extensions, how to replace any dot except the last dot of the file extension with a "_"

eg. sampleMaliciousPHPTextfile.php.txt would be renamed to sampleMaliciousPHPTextfile_php.txt using regex

Comment: explode at `.`, pop the last element off of the resulting array, implode the rest with `_` again, and concat `.` plus last element back to the end …

Comment: *"There is a vulnerability in apache where a file sampleText.php.txt may be uploaded to a directory"* [citation needed] ... I'd like to know the exact details of the vulnerability to see if this is the best way to mitigate it, do you have a link?

Comment: You could play with a regex like following: `preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);`, with args: `pattern:` `/([\w])\.(.*)?\.txt/`, `$replacement:` `$1_$2.txt` and `$string:` ` `sampleMaliciousPHPTextfile.php.txt` is turned into: `sampleMaliciousPHPTextfile_php.txt `

Comment: Right - so the *best* way to mitigate it then is to configure Apache properly, based on information linked to in the duplicate question... carry on.

Comment: About the vulnerabilty, I was reading the Double extensions section on [link](https://www.acunetix.com/websitesecurity/upload-forms-threat/)

Comment: Right, so you've got the _best_ way and _other_ ways at your disposal,... go on.